# SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised using IE9 and Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO for a NodeJS web application. The page is served on SSL and my connection looks like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('/');
```

This works on pretty much any browser except IE9. On IE9 (in Windows 7), I get this error in the console:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://app.mysite.com/socket.io/1/htmlfile/m9Zjap56uyEbx4eptg27?t=1375727354386
```

The socket never connects.  The type of SSL is SNI and the page that is running the code is on the same sub-domain.  For example: https://app.mysite.com/project/show/12345

I've also tried the following, but it made no difference:

```
var socket = io.connect('/', { secure: true });
```

Any ideas how I can make it work on IE9?

Answer (score 0):

What transports are you using? I know IE9 has trouble with true websockets so falling back to something like flashsockets might work for you. Try something like this:

```
io.set('transports', [
     'websocket'
   , 'flashsocket'
   , 'htmlfile'
   , 'xhr-polling'
   , 'jsonp-polling'
 ]);
```

Ideally IE9 would fail with websockets and then succeed with flashsockets (Port 10843 and should count as secure).

Comment: I was hopeful, but this did not resolve the issue. I also made sure flash was installed, but that did not help. Thanks anyways